# Генерация сильных простых чисел

Tags: python, алгоритм, формулы

Помогите пожалуйста решить задачу.

> Алгоритм Гордона для генерации сильно простого числа:
>
> 1. Сгенерировать два больших простых числа **s** и **t** одной длины.
> 2. Выбрать число **i0**. Найти первое простое число в последовательности **2it + 1**, где **i = i0**, **i = i + 1**, .... Обозначить это число **r = 2it + 1**.
> 3. Вычислить **p0 = 2 (s^r-2 mod r) s - 1**.
> 4. Выбрать число **j0**. Найти первое простое число в последовательности **p0 + 2jrs**, где **j = j0**, **j = j + 1**, .... Обозначить это число **p = p0 + 2jrs**.
> 5. Вернуть **p**.

Реализовал все пункты, кроме *2* и *4*.
В *втором пункте* нужно найти число **r**.
В *четвертом пункте* нужно найти число **p**.

Возможно в обеих пунктах нужно использовать циклы, но я пока не понимаю как их правильно написать, чтобы вычислить числа **r** и **p**.

```
# Пункт 1
s = 78479 # Сгенерированное число s
t = 86399 # Сгенерированное число t

# Пункт 2
i0 = 3 # Выбранное число i0
r = None # Проблема здесь

# Пункт 3
p0 = 2 * (pow(s, r - 2) % r) * s - 1 # Вычисленное число p0

# Пункт 4
j0 = 9 # Выбранное число j0
p = None # Проблема здесь

# Пункт 5
print(p) # Вывод числа p
```